# Optical or laser communication?

Tags: digital-communications

I am reading about satellite communication and have found a very interesting topic for me: optical communication in satellite communication. It is not a new concept but a lot of researches are made.
There are some doubts:

1. What is a difference between optical and laser communication for satellite?
2. I have read, in optical communication, no special antennas are needed for communication. I thought we need a special antenna (high power or something else) for transmission a signal to avoid obstacles ( atmosphere, cosmic objects…

Answer (score 1):

> What is a difference between optical and laser communication for satellite?

Lasers are *one* type of optical communication. I'd guess all satellite optical comms *are* laser-based.

So, there's no difference.

> I have read, in optical communication, no special antennas are needed for communication.

... Unless you realize that a lens is actually just a kind of dielectric antenna for terahertz radiation. So, while technically you'd not call these things "antennas", you need very very special optical elements - which typically are much more expensive, and tend to be heavy.

> I thought we need a special antenna (high power or something else) for transmission a signal to avoid obstacles ( atmosphere, cosmic objects

That sentence makes no sense, physically. Point of calling something "optical" is that it has optical propagation properties. You hence can't "avoid" obstacles.

Comment: ist beam size then important parameter of laser communication? ( wide or narrow) "`... a lens is actually just a kind of dielectric antenna for terahertz radiation...`"

Comment: do you mean beam diameter? How do you define that over multiple hundred km of beam length? I think you're asking new questions in the comments that aren't really about signal processing.

Comment: ah....sorry. Could you suggest a good reference about design a receiver or a transmitter in laser satelite communication ( lens, diods, ...)

Comment: Thank you Mr Müller for taking time to answer this question! have a nice one!

Comment: you'll need a basis in technical optics. There's quite a few textbooks on that. Since you seem to be into research, my guess is you might be at a research institution: Check what the librarians there have to recommend on technical optics.